# (electron-store) How can I use "patternProperties" when define schema

Tags: json, validation, electron, config, jsonschema

I am using library for my electron app called [electron-store](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store)

It has a feature to validate config data.

I want the value to be stored in config file is a string. I can achive that by define schema like this:

```
const schema = {
    1: {
        type: 'string',
    },
    2: {
        type: 'string',
    },
    3: {
        type: 'string',
    },
    4: {
        type: 'string',
    },
};

const store = new Store({schema});
```

The data in my config.json file:

```
{
   "1": "lorem epsum...",
   "2": "epsum lorem...",
   "3": "epsum epsum...",
   "4": "lorem lorem..."
}
```

The problem is I have hundreds line of datas like that, so it would be great if I could just define:

```
const schema = {
    [any_key_name]: {
        type: 'string',
    },
};
```

I think I can use "patternProperties" when defining schema to achive it but I don't know how. help me please.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you cannot do this with `electron-store` as you want.

The docs say the following:

> You should define your schema as an object where each key is the name
> of your data's property and each value is a JSON schema used to
> validate that property.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store#schema

This means that the root "schema" is not a JSON Schema. Only the value of each KEY is a JSON Schema.

If you want to use dynamic names, I think you would need to nest it under a specific key name, and validate that as a single object, although this is **probably not** what you really want to do with a store.

Sorry, I'm not familiar with `electron-store` specifically.

---

If you COULD provide a full JSON Schema for the whole store...

You can use `patternProperties`.
If you don't need to check the key follows any specific regex, you can use `additionalProperties`, which would then cover all properties not checked by `properties` (if present).

LEt's look at the specification: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.6

> The value of "additionalProperties" MUST be a valid JSON Schema.
>
> This keyword determines how child instances validate for objects,
> and    does not directly validate the immediate instance itself.
>
> Validation with "additionalProperties" applies only to the child
> values of instance names that do not match any names in "properties",
> and do not match any regular expression in "patternProperties".

As a pure JSON Schema, you'd be looking at...

```
{
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```

You can easily test this using [https://jsonschema.dev](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEBDAJhglgF2wPbxoA2ACgE4EAOAphfrWKpInEsiiLgJ50tcwuCtngBzVAmQBfBNJAAaENigwpyVAEYBmgEwBmBeq66BqWtTABXALaISBCrRsA6N6iMcu+syAvW7f1s3Fw9jVAAWXwcnOxjnEMl4eWkgA) (link has an example for you)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I'd very like to implement "additionalProperties" but I don't know how to do that with electron-store

Comment: Updated my answer. It looks like electron-store takes a JSON Schema per key, and your top level "schema" is not a JSON Schema.